# In a perfectly competitive market, how are the market demands taken into consideration?

Tags: microeconomics, perfect-competition

In a perfectly competitive market, how are the market demands taken into consideration? Or is it that the market demand isn't a concept there as such due to a very large market and setting the price more will attract no consumer and less will attract as many consumers as will $p^*$, the market price?

When maximizing profit $\pi_i = pq_i - c(q_i)$ for firm $i$, we do not mention the market (inverse) demand $p(q)$ curve anywhere. This led me to ask this question.

---

Edit: Slightly unrelated to my main question. While searching for a tag along the lines of perfect-competition, I saw competitive equilibrium. Is perfect competition also a competitive equilibrium?

Comment: Supply can be complementary in perfect equilibrium but usually it is revenue above inverse demand, costs, does p\* make. The trades *still happen along q* with ordinary profits, but *the **more eager participants actually get a better deal*** having the prices be made for them. `marginal demand utility == costs in perfect competition + ordinary profit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, market demand is in there. The assumption of perfectly competitive market is that firm is a price taker. Consequently market demand is perfectly elastic so the inverse demand function that **individual firm** faces is given by:

$$p(q_i)= \bar{p}$$

Once you substitute this inverse demand into profit function you get:

$$\Pi = p(q_i)q_i - c(q_i)=\bar{p}q_i-c(q_i)$$

I use $\bar{}$ to emphasize that price is fixed but most undergraduate textbooks just use $p$. Nonetheless, the demand is still there, just the demand one single firm faces is always perfectly elastic and independent of production of a single firm (even if demand for whole market isn't).

> Is perfect competition also a competitive equilibrium?

Perfect competition is a model. A competitive equilibrium can be an equilibrium found in perfectly competitive model, but equilibrium itself is balance of various forces (e.g. supply-demand, revenue-costs etc.) or situation where players play their best response to what other players are playing.

Comment: I do get the idea but I still don't see the complete picture. I posted a [follow-up question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/53003/perfect-competition-allocations). If time permits, please check. Thank you.